# How to return array from label offset expression?

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression, rule-based

I am trying to set the x,y offset of layer labels based on a data defined override. What I'm trying is the following:

```
CASE
WHEN name is 'Brooklyn Bridge' [3.5, 0]
ELSE [-3.5, 0]
END
```

However this does not seem to be the correct syntax to set x and y values simultaneously. How would you do this?

Comment: also you have missed comma: `ELSE [-3.5 0]` -> `ELSE [-3.5, 0]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just needed to use "=" instead of "is", surround your field name with "", and replace the () with '' around the offset values, see expression below:

```
CASE
WHEN "name" = 'Brooklyn Bridge' THEN '3.5, 0'
ELSE '-3.5, 0'
END
```